# How do you delete a Department in the Azure EA Portal?

Tags: azure, azureportal

How do you delete a Department in the Azure EA Portal?

I know I can go into the EA Portal and manually delete it, but is there some way to programmatically delete it?

*... and the corollary question ...*

Is there some way to programmatically create one?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, and as of Today (2016-05-09) there is no management / REST interface for the EA Portal. Currently there are only Azure Management REST APIs (both for Azure Service and Resource Managers). There is also Billing API, which is a read-only and can only look for pricies - both for offered services and consumed services. But there is no REST API, using which you can manage the EA portal. Only through the EA Portal.